# How to make a Vaadin-grid column of width 1px?

Tags: javascript, java, html, vaadin, vaadin-grid

I tried to make a column width of 1px in a vaadin grid. 
I tried the following:

```
grid.columns[0].flex = 0;
grid.columns[0].minWidth = 1;
grid.columns[0].maxWidth = 1;
grid.columns[0].width = 1;
```

It still has a width of 48px.

**How to make a Vaadin-grid column of width 1px?**

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the padding of the `.vaadin-grid-cell` elements to 0. That will get you at least closer to 1px, but seems like it still has at least 10px minimum width.

Comment: The reason I wanne do this is to have an id column which I can find with gwtquery. Do you see any better way of doing this?

Comment: I would use the rowClassGenerator function for that instead.